# post php array to ajax using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I have the following :

```
<script charset="UTF-8">
function deleter(theid) {
    var namme = document.getElementById(theid).id;
    $.post( "sql_machine.php",  { 
        selection_name: select_namme
    })
}
</script>
```

using jquery, would it be possible to post a php array too? may be encoding it as json? 
like the following?

```
<script charset="UTF-8">
function deleter(theid) {
    var select_namme = document.getElementById(theid).id;
    $.post( "sql_machine_tomskus.php",  { 
        selection_name: select_namme,
        { array : dataToSend }
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you can send an array.

Comment: what did u mean with php array ? dataToSend is an array comming from php ?

Comment: yes I have a php array that I'd like to post trough an AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to send the array, and to decode it to array in php, use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

In JQ:

```
<script charset="UTF-8">
function deleter(theid) {
    var select_namme = document.getElementById(theid).id;
    $.post( "sql_machine_tomskus.php",  { 
        selection_name: select_namme,
        array : JSON.stringify(yourArrayOrObject)
    })
}
</script>
```

Then, in php just use `json_decode($_POST["array"])`

Comment: thanks and how could I "send" the array to the function?? Also shoud I jsonencode it?

Comment: @markoc. just save the array into `yourArrayOrObject` or place it right there...

`var yourArrayOrObject = {name: 'vlad'};`, or you can place the array right inside the AJAX call: `array : JSON.stringify({name: 'vlad'})`

Answer (score 0):

thanksGINCHER here it is my final solution :

```
    <script charset="UTF-8">
        function deleter(theid) {
            var select_namme = document.getElementById(theid).id;
            $.post( "sql_machine.php",  { 
                selection_name: select_namme,
                array : <?echo json_encode($array);?>
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Both `JSON.stringify` and `json_encode` do the same action. If you already have it in JSON you don't have to convert it to JSON. Just do it like this: `array : "<?echo json_encode($array);?>"`

Comment: Add error checking if this is intended for a production environment. You can thank me later ;)